# How can I setup DateTime hour,minute and second?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime, seconds

```
private void StartAuction()
{
    DateTime closeDate;
    closeDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

I am able to set the date,month and year but I want the hours,minutes and seconds to setup automatically to the current time of the day. for example if the current time is `15:24`, I want the user to add the date which could be `21/03/2013` and then I want the time to be 15:24:00 and not `00:00:00` as it currently does.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The first thing to do is not nest functions.  It makes your code hard to read, debug and maintain.

Comment: Consider using `TryParse` to handle errors in a graceful manner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well you can use `DateTime.Now` to get the current time, then take the [`TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) from that and add it to the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) of your existing `DateTime`:

```
private void StartAuction()
{
    DateTime closeDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    DateTime closeDateAtCurrentTime = closeDate.Date + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    ...
}
```

(I'm explicitly using the `Date` property so that even if the user *does* enter a time as well, it's basically stripped.)

As a blatant plug, you might also want to consider using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library, which separates out the ideas of "date", "time" and "date/time" into different types. (As well as "local" values vs ones where you know the UTC offset or the time zone.)

Comment: Incorporated your use of `.Date` in my own answer which I'm keeping around simply for the fact that I wanted to explain the point you commented about - converting strings back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do

```
closeDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine() + " " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
```

Which works, but does look a little roundabout and I wouldn't recommend it considering you're converting *from* a time format to a string and then back to a time format again. Lots of immutable objects being created, there.

There are other options, including to parse the date, as you do, and *then* add `TimeOfDay` to it.

```
DateTime closeDate;
closeDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
closeDate = closeDate.Date + Date.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it as part of the parsing part - you might as well parse it and *then* add the value. I generally prefer my code to have as few string conversions as possible :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I was writing out an alternative just as I saw your answer pop up. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var date = new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, input.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to parse with [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/1k1skd40.aspx) what you read from command line.

Then, you can do that using [`DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) like;

```
DateTime closeDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
closeDate = closeDate.Date + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
closeDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
    .Add(DateTime.Now - DateTime.Today);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well how about this little function:

```
public static DateTime ChangeTime(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return new DateTime(
        dateTime.Year,
        dateTime.Month,
        dateTime.Day,
        DateTime.Now.Hour,
        DateTime.Now.Minute,
        DateTime.Now.Second,
        DateTime.Now.Millisecond,
        DateTime.Now.Kind);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

store DateTime.Now in a variable

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
```

Then u can access the Hours, Minutes and Seconds like this:

```
date.Hour;
date.Minute;
date.Second;
```